# Global variable vs class variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, bestpractice, global-variables

I have been using a global variable such as $UserInfo.getUiThemeDisplayed in a visualforce page several times for rendered conditions. In this case which is better, using a class variable or global variable on the page.

Comment: Better for what ? Please provide us with more info on what you're really trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Throughout your work on the platform, it is generally better to avoid `Apex` if you can. This case is no different, especially if it makes the difference between using a controller extension or not. The main reason you might want to reference a controller variable instead, is if you need to access that property in other pieces of controller code as well. In such a case, it may be better to have a unified reference.